# Convert a JSON representation of CSV data to actual CSV data

Tags: json, powershell, csv

This self-answered question is about transforming a JSON representation of CSV data into actual CSV data.<sup>[1]</sup>

The following JSON contains separate properties that describe the headers (column names) (`columns`) and arrays of corresponding row values (`rows`), respectively:

```json
{
  "columns": [
      {
          "name": "ColumnName1",
          "type": "Number"
      },
      {
          "name": "ColumnName2",
          "type": "String"
      },
      {
          "name": "ColumnName3",
          "type": "String"
      }
  ],
  "rows":    [
      [
          11111,
          "ResourceType1",
          "String1"
      ],
      [
          22222,
          "ResourceType2",
          "String2"
      ],
      [
          33333,
          "ResourceType3",
          "String3"
      ]
  ]
}
```

How can I convert this JSON input to the CSV data it represents?

---

<sup>[1] The question duplicates [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69274286/45375), which was closed presumably due to lack of effort, even though what it asks for is reasonably well-defined.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that CSV files have no concept of *data types* - all values are *strings*,
so the data-type information (from the `.column.type` properties) is lost, unless you choose to incorporate it
in some way as a *convention* that the consumer of the CSV would have to be aware of (the code below does *not* do that).

Assume that the JSON in the question is saved in file `file.json`, which can be parsed into a (`[pscustomobject]`) object graph with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), via reading the file *as text* with  [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content):

```bash
# Convert the JSON text into a [pscustomobject] object graph.
$fromJson = ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content -Raw file.json)

# Process the array of column names and the arrays of row values by
# enclosing the array elements in "..." and joining them with ","
(, $fromJson.Columns.Name + $fromJson.Rows).ForEach({
  $_.ForEach({ '"{0}"' -f ($_ -replace '"', '""') }) -join ','
})
```

Note that the above encloses the column names and values in `"..."` so as to also support
names and values with *embedded* `,` characters; additionally, any embedded `"` characters are properly escaped by *doubling* them.

If you know that the input data neither contains values with embedded `,` nor
`"`, you can simply omit the inner [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)
call above, which will result in *unquoted* values.

The above outputs:

```
"ColumnName1","ColumnName2","ColumnName3"
"11111","ResourceType1","String1"
"22222","ResourceType2","String2"
"33333","ResourceType3","String3"
```

- To convert the above *in-memory* to (`[pscustomobject]`) objects representing the CSV data, use [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) (`...` represents the command above):

  ```bash
  ... | ConvertFrom-Csv
  ```
- To save the above to a *CSV file*, use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content):

  ```bash
  ... | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 out.csv
  ```